# Range format md-pagination Angular Material

Tags: angular, pagination, format, range, material-design

I'm using ng2-material and I would like to know if it's possible to format pagination to work with pages instead of row numbers?

I think they follow data table specs from Material Design and then you can only display pagination data like `1 - 10 of 100`?

I would like to know if it's possible to show pagination like `Page 1 of 3`

In the docs you can see that `rangeFormat` only accepts `{start}`, `{end}` and `{total}` values but it's not helpful. Is it possible to manipulate this values in some way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question:

I've used a workaround and I'll leave it here in case someone need it in the future.

Using the `<md-pagination>` to achieve what I wanted I need to use `itemsPerPageAfter` option.

End up like this

```
<md-pagination [model]="pagination" name="basic" (on-pagination-change)="detectChange($event)" [items-per-page-options]="availableLength" [range]="false" items-per-page-after="Page {{pagination.currentPage }} of {{totalPages}}"></md-pagination>
```

it was necessary to apply custom css (same used in rangeFormat option).

Result
[image]